acceso simultaneo con dos certificados digitales al SII
Estoy descargando las facturas emitidas y recibidas sin ningún problema del SII de la AEAT con un cerfificado en formato pfx de una empresa en concreto.
Sin embargo si desde la misma maquina JVM una vez hecha la primera conexión intento conectar con otro pfx a una empresa diferente me sigue usando el certificado de la primera conexión, devolviendome un error la AEAT de que el certificado no es valido para esta nueva empresa.
Alguien sabe como limpiar la configuracion de webservices ( jax-ws ) sin tener que tirar la maquina JVM?
Los ws services consumidos los obtengo de los wsdl descargados en JAVA
** codigo **
SiiService service = new SiiService(); SiiSOAP siiSOAP = null; siiSOAP = service.getSuministroFactEmitidasPruebas();
